# no me recupera los datos de una base de datos, los inserta bien pero no los recupera

Tags: java

tengo este código, en el actionListener del botonRecuperar intento recuperar por medio de una consulta a la base de datos el nombre y apellido a través de la semilla numérica, pero no me los recupera y no me da error de ningún tipo. Voy a dejar por aquí también la clase de conexión a la base de datos con los modos correspondientes.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 *         public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Ejemplo de uso
        ConexionBD conexionBD = new ConexionBD("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Formulario_CBSD", "root", "root1234");
        

        // Insertar datos en la tabla "nombre_de_la_tabla"
        conexionBD.insertarDatos("usuarios", "OLAYA","BENAMEUR",4);

        // Cerrar la conexión B
        conexionBD.cerrarConexion();
    }
 */
class ConexionBD implements AutoCloseable {

    private Connection conexion;
    private String rNombre;
    private String rApellidos;

    public String obtenerRNombre() {
        return rNombre;
    }

    public String obtenerRApellidos() {
        return rApellidos;
    }

    // Constructor: Establecer la conexión a la base de datos
    public ConexionBD(String url, String usuario, String contraseña) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            this.conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Método para cerrar la conexión
    public void cerrarConexion() {
        if (conexion != null) {
            try {
                conexion.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    // Método para hacer la inserción de datos
    public void insertarDatos(String tabla, String nombre, String apellido, long semilla) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conexion.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO " + tabla + " (nombre, apellido, semilla) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {

            preparedStatement.setString(1, nombre);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, apellido);
            preparedStatement.setLong(3, semilla);

            int filasAfectadas = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            if (filasAfectadas > 0) {
                System.out.println("Inserción exitosa");
            } else {
                System.out.println("La inserción no tuvo éxito");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        cerrarConexion();
    }




    //metodo para buscar en la base de datos la semilla y recuperar los nombres y apellidos
    public void recuperarDatos(long semilla){
    String consultaSQL = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM usuarios WHERE semilla = ? ";

    try (PreparedStatement conexion1Statement = conexion.prepareStatement(consultaSQL)) {
        conexion1Statement.setLong(1, semilla);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = conexion1Statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                 rNombre = resultSet.getString(1);
                 rApellidos = resultSet.getString(2);

                System.out.println("Nombre: " + rNombre + " " + rApellidos);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Imprime la traza de la excepción para depuración
        System.err.println("Error SQL: " + e.getErrorCode() + ", Mensaje: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

    private JTextField nombreField, apellidoField, resultadoField, contraseñaField, recuperarContraseñaField;
    private JButton boton, botonRecuperar;

    public MainGUI() {
        // Configuración básica de la ventana
        setTitle("Formulario_CBSD");
        setSize(500, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Crear un JPanel con layout nulo
        JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel(null);
        panelPrincipal.setBackground(new Color(200, 255, 200)); // Color de fondo verde claro

        // Inicialización de componentes
        nombreField = new JTextField();
        apellidoField = new JTextField();
        resultadoField = new JTextField();
        boton = new JButton("Guardar");
        contraseñaField = new JTextField();
        recuperarContraseñaField = new JTextField();
        botonRecuperar = new JButton("Recuperar");

        // Configuración de colores y bordes si es necesario
        nombreField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        apellidoField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // Establecer tamaño y posición manualmente
        nombreField.setBounds(90, 50, 150, 30);
        apellidoField.setBounds(90, 100, 150, 30);
        resultadoField.setBounds(90, 200, 300, 30);
        boton.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
        contraseñaField.setBounds(100, 250, 200, 30);
        recuperarContraseñaField.setBounds(100, 350, 200, 30);
        botonRecuperar.setBounds(50, 400, 100, 30);

        // Añadir componentes al panel
        JLabel nombreLabel = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        nombreLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 70, 30);
        panelPrincipal.add(nombreLabel);
        panelPrincipal.add(nombreField);

        JLabel apellidoLabel = new JLabel("Apellido:");
        apellidoLabel.setBounds(10, 100, 70, 30);
        panelPrincipal.add(apellidoLabel);
        panelPrincipal.add(apellidoField);

        panelPrincipal.add(new JLabel("Resultado:"));
        panelPrincipal.add(resultadoField);
        panelPrincipal.add(boton);

        JLabel contraseñaLabel = new JLabel("Contraseña:");
        contraseñaLabel.setBounds(10, 250, 150, 30);
        panelPrincipal.add(contraseñaLabel);
        panelPrincipal.add(contraseñaField);

        JLabel recuperarDatosLabel = new JLabel("Obtener");
        recuperarDatosLabel.setBounds(10, 350, 200, 30);
        panelPrincipal.add(recuperarDatosLabel);
        panelPrincipal.add(recuperarContraseñaField);
        panelPrincipal.add(botonRecuperar);

        // Añadir el panelPrincipal a la ventana
        add(panelPrincipal);

        boton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String nombre = nombreField.getText();
            String apellido = apellidoField.getText();
            GeneradorRandomConSemillaNumerica generador = new GeneradorRandomConSemillaNumerica();
            long numeroAleatorioLargo = generador.generarNumeroAleatorioLargo();

            // Insertar datos en la base de datos
            try (ConexionBD conexionBD = new ConexionBD("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Formulario_CBSD", "root",
                    "root1234")) {
                conexionBD.insertarDatos("usuarios", nombre, apellido, numeroAleatorioLargo);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Manejar la excepción apropiadamente (mostrar un mensaje de error, etc.)
            }

            // Concatenar los valores recibidos y mostrarlos en el JTextField de resultado
            resultadoField.setText("Nombre: " + nombre + ", Apellido: " + apellido);

            contraseñaField.setText("=" + numeroAleatorioLargo);
        });

        botonRecuperar.addActionListener(i -> {
            String apellidosFuera = null;
            String nombreFuera = null;
            String recuperarSemillaString = recuperarContraseñaField.getText();

            try {
                Long recuperarSemilla = Long.parseLong(recuperarSemillaString);

                try (ConexionBD conexionBD2 = new ConexionBD("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Formulario_CBSD", "root",
                        "root1234")) {
                    conexionBD2.recuperarDatos(recuperarSemilla);
                    nombreFuera = conexionBD2.obtenerRNombre();
                    apellidosFuera = conexionBD2.obtenerRApellidos();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    // Manejar la excepción apropiadamente (mostrar un mensaje de error, etc.)
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                // Manejar la excepción apropiadamente (mostrar un mensaje de error, etc.)
            }

            resultadoField.setText("Nombre: " + (nombreFuera != null ? nombreFuera : "") + ", Apellido: "
                    + (apellidosFuera != null ? apellidosFuera : ""));
        });

        // Mover setVisible(true) fuera del bloque try-catch
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Puedes probar la GUI creando una instancia de MainGUI
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainGUI::new);
    }
}
```

estoy haciendo un formulario donde metes un nombre y apellido para que sea guardado en una base de datos con una contraseña única, esta contraseña sirve para que con ella misma se puedan recuperar los datos asociados de la base de datos.